# Developer plugin to echo template names/filepaths

Tags: plugins, templates

I am looking for a Wordpress plugin that prints file template names, maybe with a designating border. Magento has "template hints", as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: magento]

If there is not such a plugin and someone would like to develop it with me, let's do that, too!

Comment: Have you already (a) tried something and (b) searched the site? I know that I have written an answer about exactly that some time ago.

Comment: a) I have looked around the internet with various keywords such as wordpress, template, hints, path, print, echo, file path, plugin. I found a dead plugin called templatepath that isn't compatible anymore.

b) Searched the site with similar keywords but I didn't really find anything. I did find your answer though! Thank you.

Comment: However, that solution doesn't really provide the front-end visualization of files. It just prints a list of files loaded by that page. While good, it's not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a plugin called Query Monitor, that does a whole bunch of stuff, including showing the page's template. It's in the WordPress Repo.

Comment: Please add a link to the plugin and info from the plugin page to show what the plugin does

Comment: Find it right over here in the Wordpress plugin repo: [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) "View debugging and performance information on database queries, hooks, conditionals, HTTP requests, redirects and more."

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I use.  It will display the current template file name to logged-in users.  Paste this in your functions.php file and comment out/remove when not in use.

```
// REMOVE - show template name
  add_action('wp_head', 'show_template');
  function show_template() {
  global $template;
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  if ($current_user->user_level == 10 ) print_r($template);
  }
// REMOVE - end show template name
```

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/developer-toolbar/ this plugin also can be tried